# How to open Windows 7 firewall for self hosted basic-http WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, firewall

I have added a rule to the firewall to open TCP port 8080 used by my WCF-service app (self hosted basic-http). Everything works fine as along as I check "All applications..." and not the specific exe-file of my app in the rule. Ive googled the problem and found out that a deamon process (SMSvcHost.exe) is used to host the service, but only when using net-tcp and Im using basic-http. The client is a Windows Phone 7-app so I cant use net-tcp. But what daemon-process is being used for basic-http? And what would be the easiest way of adding this rule to the firewall programatically when my service-app is starting for the first time?

Comment: I'm in the same boat, only with the WCF WebApi stack hosted in a Windows Service.  For now, I went down the same road as you, manually adjusting the firewall to open the port to the world.  Far from ideal, looking forward to hearing answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I know W3WP.exe handles the app pools, but I'm not sure about the HTTP hosting.  I've personally never done a rule that applied a certain port to an application, but rather one or the other.

I hope that at least is something helpful :)

Comment: Adding a rule to W3WP.exe didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the netstat command with the -o option to figure out which PID is listening on that port.  Then look Task Manager to figure out which exe belongs to that PID.

Comment: This only returned PID 4 (System).